# WordPress JSON API displaying a post with images in Android

Tags: android, json, wordpress, image

I'm writing an Android app for a WordPress website. I've figured get how to 'get' posts and display them in a listView and make them clickable.

The problem is once the post is clicked on, I want to display each post as it is on the original website, i.e. with the images in the same positions as they are on the website (intersparsed with the text). I know how to get the text and images separately but how can I format them in the correct way? (I don't know how many images there will be in a post)

Answer (score -1):

you can open a WebView and in the wordpress you can create a new template to show just the post without the menus.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Is this what other apps for websites implement?

Comment: i dont know. what is the original post view in the website that you can imitate with android controls?

Comment: Each post is essentially an article. I need the article content and the pictures but in the same order as the original.
Is this the only way?